# gstreamer android ndk-build error undefined reference to 'xx'

Tags: android-ndk, gstreamer

I use streamer at  Click [here]http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development.
But when i ndk-build , it error .who can help me ,thinks!

Platform:
ubuntu 12.10 x64

Log:

/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lGLESv2
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lEGL
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lOpenSLES
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-opensles.o): in function gst_opensles_get_engine:opensles.c:41: error: undefined reference to 'slCreateEngine'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslessink.o): in function gst_opensles_sink_init:openslessink.c:283: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_AUDIOIODEVICECAPABILITIES'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function _opensles_recorder_acquire:openslesringbuffer.c:179: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function _opensles_recorder_acquire:openslesringbuffer.c:179: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_RECORD'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function _opensles_player_acquire:openslesringbuffer.c:327: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function _opensles_player_acquire:openslesringbuffer.c:327: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_VOLUME'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function _opensles_player_acquire:openslesringbuffer.c:327: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_PLAY'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function gst_opensles_ringbuffer_open_device:openslesringbuffer.c:747: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_ENGINE'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgstopensles.a(libgstopensles_la-openslesringbuffer.o): in function gst_opensles_ringbuffer_open_device:openslesringbuffer.c:747: error: undefined reference to 'SL_IID_OUTPUTMIX'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:942: error: undefined reference to 'glViewport'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:950: error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:951: error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:488: error: undefined reference to 'glDeleteBuffers'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:489: error: undefined reference to 'glDeleteBuffers'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:604: error: undefined reference to 'glGenBuffers'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:605: error: undefined reference to 'glGenBuffers'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:609: error: undefined reference to 'glBindBuffer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:613: error: undefined reference to 'glBufferData'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:619: error: undefined reference to 'glBindBuffer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:624: error: undefined reference to 'glBufferData'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:965: error: undefined reference to 'glUseProgram'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:967: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:972: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:978: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:983: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:990: error: undefined reference to 'glUseProgram'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:993: error: undefined reference to 'glUniform1i'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:998: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:1003: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexAttribPointer'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function gst_eglglessink_render:gsteglglessink.c:1008: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawElements'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:750: error: undefined reference to 'glActiveTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:751: error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:756: error: undefined reference to 'glActiveTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:757: error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:772: error: undefined reference to 'glActiveTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:773: error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/home/denghaizhu/Software/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: /home/denghaizhu/projects/gstreamSDK/lib/gstreamer-0.10/static/libgsteglglessink.a(libgsteglglessink_la-gsteglglessink.o): in function render_thread_func:gsteglglessink.c:774: error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'

Comment: Could you please provide your `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`